# SARSA value approximation for Cart Pole

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, sarsa

I have a question on [this](https://github.com/ceteke/RL/blob/master/Approximation/Linear%20Sarsa.ipynb) SARSA FA.

In input cell 142 I see this modified update

```
w += alpha * (reward - discount * q_hat_next) * q_hat_grad
```

where `q_hat_next` is `Q(S', a')` and `q_hat_grad` is the derivative of `Q(S, a)` (assume `S, a, R, S' a'` sequence).

My question is shouldn't the update should be like this?

```
w += alpha * (reward + discount * q_hat_next - q_hat) * q_hat_grad
```

What is the intuition behind the modified update?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct. I would also have expected that the update contains the TD error term, which should be `reward + discount * q_hat_next - q_hat`.

For reference, this is the implementation:

```
if done: # (terminal state reached)
   w += alpha*(reward - q_hat) * q_hat_grad
   break
else:
   next_action = policy(env, w, next_state, epsilon)
   q_hat_next = approx(w, next_state, next_action)
   w += alpha*(reward - discount*q_hat_next)*q_hat_grad
   state = next_state
```

And this is pseudo-code from [Reinforcement Learning:
An Introduction (by Sutton & Barto)](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf) (page 171):

[image]

As the implementation is TD(0), `n` is 1. Then the update in the pseudo-code can be simplified:

```
w <- w + a[G - v(S_t,w)] * dv(S_t,w)
```

becomes (by substituting `G == reward + discount*v(S_t+1,w))`)

```
w <- w + a[reward + discount*v(S_t+1,w) - v(S_t,w)] * dv(S_t,w)
```

Or with the variable names in the original code example:

```
w += alpha * (reward + discount * q_hat_next - q_hat) * q_hat_grad
```

I ended up with the same update formula that you have. Looks like a bug in the non-terminal state update.

Only the terminal case (if `done` is true) should be correct because then `q_hat_next` is always 0 by definition, as the episode is over and no more reward can be gained.